# Getting index from child to parent in react

Tags: reactjs

I have child component using map I am rendering it how can I pass the index to the parent component method.

React version is 15, how can I get the index using bind method with this also

```
// child.js

render(){
  return(
   {
    this.state.map((d, index) => {
      <p onClick={() => this.props.handleMethod(index)}>d</p>
    })

   }
  )
}

// parent.js

_handle =(self, index, id) => {
  console.log(self,index, id) // get o, 1, 2 what ever the index i clicked 
}

render(){
  return(
    <Child handleMethod={this._handle.bind(this, index, 123)}/> // how can i pass index here
  )
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(index)` in the parent.js  give you?

Comment: i need three params to pass self, index and id

Comment: did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 2):

First, the `_handle` function is using arrow syntax, so you don't need to `bind(this)` like normal function. Because `this` inside `_handle` alway point to you Class

```
// child.js

  render1(){
    return(
      this.state.map((d, index) => (
        <p onClick={() => this.props.handleMethod(index)}>d</p>
      ))
    )
  }

  // parent.js

  _handle = (index, id) => {
    // In arrow function, this alway point to this Class, you don't need to bind(this).
    console.log(this, index, id);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Child handleMethod={(index) => this._handle(index, 123)}/>
    )
  }
```

Live version here: https://codesandbox.io/s/4r06wz4vn4?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.handleMethod.bind(this, index, param1, param2)

handleMethod(index, param1, param2) {
}
```

Did you tried this?

Comment: can you  check the updated question i need to pass three params

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the values that you want in handle function in parent component. Bind will return you a function that will get passed to child, call that method with the item index.

Order of these values are important, First you will get all the values you bound in parent then the values passed from child component.

Like this:

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      {
        this.state.map((d, index) => (
          <p onClick={() => this.props.handleMethod(index)}>d</p>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}

_handle = (selfIndex, id, index) => {
  console.log(index)
}

render(){
  return(
    <Child handleMethod={this._handle.bind(this, selfIndex, 123)}/>
  )
}
```

Working Example:

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {
          [1,2,3,4].map((d, index) => (
            <p onClick={() => this.props.handleMethod(index)}>{d}</p>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {

  _handle (selfIndex, id, index) {
    console.log(selfIndex, id, index)
  }

  render(){
    const selfIndex = 7;
    return(
      <Child handleMethod={this._handle.bind(this, selfIndex, 123)}/>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
p {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Comment: no i  need to get the this also , <Child handleMethod={this._handle(this, index, 123)}/> . I need to get three params in the _handle how could i get

Comment: i removed the spread operator i was trying to tell i was passing more things

Comment: so you want to get the parameter of parent and the index from child component?

Comment: yes three things, self index and id on the method as in the question

Comment: getting as 7 123 0, trying to get self(this), then 0(index), 123 (hardcoded value)

Comment: `this` will be available automatically because bind that method, just access `this` directly in that method, do `console.log('self', this)` :)

Comment: why in the working answer selfIndex is 7 as hard coded

Comment: just for example, i don't know anything about selfindex, just replace it with your actual value :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
// Child
render() {
    const content = this.state.someValue.map((d, index)=>(
        <p onClick={() => this.props.handleMethod(index, 123)}>d</p>
    ));

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            {content}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}


// Parent

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._handle = this._handle.bind(this);
}

_handle(index, extraParam){ // extraParam will hold 123
     console.log(index)
}

render() {
    return(
        <Child handleMethod={this._handle} />
    )
}
```

Notice that `state` can't be an array. It should be an object that contains a property. In my example, the property is `someValue` which is an array.

Comment: Sorry what has changed in your question?

Comment: _handle method and where i am calling the _handle passing three params this, index from child and hard coded value as 123. Check the question

Comment: First you don't need to pass any parameter from `<Child handleMethod={this._handle} />`. If you need to pass `123` as extra parameter, you will need do so from the child component like this `<p onClick={() => this.props.handleMethod(index, 123)}>d</p>`
Lastly, you don't necessary need to bind it in the `render` method. Simply add `this_handle = this._handle.bind(this)` inside your `construct`.

Comment: my requirement is i need to pass from parent the 123 not from child

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191172/discussion-between-lomse-and-dileep-thomas).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting `chat.stackoverflow.com took too long to respond.` It looks like `chat` is down. Basically, binding a function in the `render` method is bad design. In a way, you are creating the same function multiple time during every render. You should avoid that

Comment: Lastly, you can simply add `123` to the parent state and access it straight from the `_handle` method. You definitely don't need to pass it from `<Child handleMethod={this._handle} />`. Good luck!